# adding function using prototype in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i have a confusion about the benefit of using prototype for inheritance. what is the difference between defining the function(method) inside the constructor function and adding the function to the prototype property, for example:

```
function Car(name,model){
            this.name = name;
            this.model = model;
            this.GetSummary = function(){
                `The car is ${this.name} and the model is ${this.model}`;
            }
        }
```

now if i deleted this.GetSummary from the constructor function Car and add it to the prototype like this:

```
Car.prototype.GetSummary = function(){
                    `The car is ${this.name} and the model is ${this.model}`;
                }
```

what is the deference?

Comment: Slight differences, easier to say it comes down to how they load? The nature of a function is that it's loaded first-class, a class is initiated at run-time. In this case, your adjustment would be subject to being not part of the program till loaded? If that's clear?:|

Comment: First one attaches `GetSummary` as an own property to each and every instance created. The second creates a single `GetSummary` on the prototype that all instances would share.